# sqlcmd.exe does not show any interactive output on the console (CMD and Powershell)

Tags: powershell, cmd, sqlcmd

I just freshly installed SQL Server Express 2014 via Chocolatey. The service is currently running.

When I run this inside my CMD or Powershell:

```
> sqlcmd -e -S .\SQLEXPRESS
1> sp_databases;
2>
```

I get no output, it just goes to the next prompt line.

However when I use this style, I do get output:

```
> sqlcmd -e -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "sp_databases;"
sp_databases;
DATABASE_NAME                                                                                                                    DATABASE_SIZE REMARKS

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
master                                                                                                                                    7808 NULL

model                                                                                                                                     5312 NULL

msdb                                                                                                                                     37632 NULL

tempdb                                                                                                                                    2560 NULL
```

What could be the reason for this? I have no special configuration for the CMD or Powershell except some colour changes of the console.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944165/can-you-make-sqlcmd-immediately-run-each-statement-in-a-script-without-the-use-o

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to run `GO` at the end of each command. Silly.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The number resets to 1, though, as in `1>`

Comment: Didn't work for me too.